# Slides.js pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with the slides.js plugin for a portfolio and I'm having a problem with the pagination. Every time I select another item, it adds pagination bullets and the timing on the pagination gets all thrown off.

Here is what I am trying to do now, no luck so far.

```
$("#slides").slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        animationStart: function() {
            clearInterval($("#slides,.pagination").data('interval'));
        }
    });
```

Thoughts?

I've looked on the github page for the slides plugin and the issues, can't find anyone who has experienced the same issues.

https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I had to do a simple

```
$(".pagination li").remove();
```

before the slides plugin initialized. Just make sure you put this before the slides plugin starts with its parameters.